# How to put Tags on API Gateway V2 Resources using a YAML CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

How to put Tags on the following Resources using a CloudFormation Template:

- AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
- AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName
- AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage

For a generic AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api Resource I have tried the following in the Resources section of the CloudFormation Template:

```
MyApi:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api'
  Properties:
    Name: MyApi
    ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
    RouteSelectionExpression: $request.body.action
    ApiKeySelectionExpression: $request.header.x-api-key
    Tags:
      - Key: TagKey1
        Value: MyFirstTag
      - Key: TagKey2
        Value: !Ref MySecondTagAsParameter
```

In the CloudFormation Events view of Amazon Management Console, The Resource failed with the following reason:

> Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Tags} does not match type {Map}]

I looked up the Type, which appeared to be `Json` in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html):

> ```
> Tags
>   The collection of tags. Each tag element is associated with a given resource.
>   Required: No
>   Type: Json
>   Update requires: No interruption
>   Required: No
> ```

Which made me try the following:

> ```
>  Tags: !Sub "{ \"TagKey1\" : \"MyFirstTag\", \"TagKey2\" : \"${MySecondTagAsParameter}\"}"
> ```

That also did not work, prompting me to try YAML literals:

> ```
> Tags: !Sub |
>   {
>     "TagKey1": "MyFirstTag",
>     "TagKey2": "${MySecondTagAsParameter}"
>   }
> ```

That did not work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following did the trick:

> ```
> Tags:
>   TagKey1: MyFirstTag
>   TagKey2: !Ref MySecondTagAsParameter
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to the **json-like** solution:

```
      Tags: { "TagKey1": "MyFirstTag",
              "TagKey2": !Ref MySecondTagAsParameter}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name:GatewayName
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Tags:
        - Key: Project
          Value: ProjectName
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the following syntax worked:

```
Tags: 
  - 
    Key: "keyname1"
    Value: "value1"
  - 
    Key: "keyname2"
    Value: "value2"
```

Source: [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-general.html)

Comment: I've tried this multiple times for the "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api" type and it doesn't work. Is it possible this worked for you with a different type? Maybe V1 of ApiGateway?